# Spring boot camunda unit tests - async before/after

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bpmn, camunda

I have model have nested call activities. I created unit test using spring boot camunda starter. Test looks like

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class DiagramTest {


    @Autowired
    private ProcessEngine processEngine;

    @Rule
    @ClassRule
    public static ProcessEngineRule rule;

    @PostConstruct
    void initRule() {
        rule = TestCoverageProcessEngineRuleBuilder.create(processEngine).build();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ProcessEngineTests.init(processEngine);
    }

    @Test
    @Deployment(resources = {"process.bpmn", "subprocess.bpmn", "sub-subprocess.bpmn"})
    @RequiredHistoryLevel(ProcessEngineConfiguration.HISTORY_NONE)
    public void ruleUsageExample() {


        RuntimeService runtimeService = rule.getRuntimeService();
 runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("process"); }
```

My problem is that on most of the components I use async before/after and because of that subprocesses do not start. When I remove async-s it works as expected. What should be the proper way of testing async behaviour in camunda bpmn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure this will solve your problem, but it wouldn't fit in a comment.

The problem here is that the process instance is persisted and then executed via a next Thread from the threadpool, so your thread which executes the unit tests ends. 
You need to test if the job is finished via query to the process engine and execute the job manually. 
I'm using this utility method:

```
public boolean waitUntilNoActiveJobs(ProcessEngine processEngine, long wait) {
    long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout) {
        long jobCount = processEngine.getManagementService().createJobQuery().active().count();
        if (jobCount == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        final List<Job> jobs = processEngine.getManagementService().createJobQuery().list();
        jobs.forEach(job -> processEngine.getManagementService().executeJob(job.getId()));
        System.out.println("Waiting for " + jobs + " jobs");
    }
    return false;
}
```

You call it at the end of your test, the parameters seem to be obvious.

Comment: It is obviously work around but it works and for test is good enough. Thanks. I suspected this can be the problem but when to check I added Thread.sleep at the end it still didnt work. So it looks like this function is doing something else than only waits in smart way.

Comment: Yes. It also does this: `processEngine.getManagementService().executeJob(...)`.

Comment: That is really interesting why unit test does not run whole process by itself. I mean I get why it ends before job ends but why we have to force it to run all jobs. If you have any pointers to the documentation or any resource about this topic I would be grateful. Thanks anyways thats great help.

Comment: The documentation is a bit lacking. Most of the things I didn't learn from documentation I get by checking examples here: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples

Comment: This has worked for me after disabling the job executor (camunda.bpm.job-execution.enabled=false), otherwise you may face "Entity was updated by another transaction concurrently".

Comment: @abalcerek Actually this seems now to be the recommended approach by Camunda: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/process-engine/the-job-executor/#job-executor-in-a-unit-test

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for process test.

Ref: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/best-practices/development/testing-process-definitions/

You can use [Camunda Assertions](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/testing/#camunda-assertions) with `isWaitingAt` and `execute(job())` from the [doc](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/testing/assert-examples/#assertions)

```java
var processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("processKey");

assertThat(processInstance)
  .hasPassedInOrder("start_event","some_other_process")
  .isWaitingAt("sub_process_in_async_before")

execute(job());
```

or more explicit/specific from the [doc](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/testing/assert-examples/#accessing-jobs-in-the-context-of-a-process-instance-under-test)

```java
var processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("processKey");

assertThat(processInstance)
  .hasPassedInOrder("start_event","some_other_process")
  .isWaitingAt("sub_process_in_async_before")

execute(job("sub_process_in_async_before", processInstance));
```

Note: you will need to disable job executors, otherwise, the existing job executor may lock the jobs when you try to execute the jobs.

Example of disabling job executors in SpringBoot using properties below (from [doc](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/#camunda-engine-properties))

```
camunda.bpm.job-execution.enabled=false
```